# Nodes within Binary Tree nodes

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes

I'm currently building a project in which I'm building a binary tree to hold clients which are then required to hold jobs inside of them.

I have created a client class which looks like this to be stored in a binary tree:

```
public class Client
String givenName;
String surname;

public Client(String givenName, String surname) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.surname = surname;
}
```

This is just used to store client details. I also need to use this as a reference for job done for the client. My job class looks like this:

```
public class Job 
Date startTime;
Date finishTime;
String totalTime;
Date date;
String employee;
String notes;
boolean complete;

public Job(Date startTime, Date finishTime, String totalTime, Date date, String employee, String notes, boolean complete) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.finishTime = finishTime;
    this.totalTime = totalTime;
    this.date = date;
    this.employee = employee;
    this.notes = notes;
    this.complete = complete;
}


}
```

How should I go about making the client classes store the jobs for easy identification and can this be done while the clients are part of a binary tree?

Comment: Why not have each client have a `Job` or `ArrayList<Job>` instance variable? Or am I misinterpreting the question?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what operations you intend to do with the clients jobs.
An ArrayList works fine. If you do many lookups on clients jobs or want to process them in sorted order (by date for example), a HashSet or TreeSet may be better.

There's no problem in adding jobs to the Client objects. The binary tree will contain references to the objects. If an object is modified, the reference in the binary tree will still point to it.